# jQuery confirm delete modal not showing Laravel 5.4

Tags: jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a "confirm deletion" modal in my Laravel 5.4 application.
I made a .blade.php file with my model so I can reuse it multiple times.

My screen only fades a bit like it should when showing the modal but the modal actually doesn't show up.

confirm-delete-modal.blade.php

```
<div class="modal fade" id="confirm-delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@lang('elements.modal.delete.title')</h4>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>@lang('elements.modal.delete.text')</p>
                <p class="debug-url"></p>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">@lang('elements.modal.delete.cancelbtn')</button>
                <a class="btn btn-danger btn-ok">@lang('elements.modal.delete.deletebtn')</a>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Where I trigger the modal:

```
<button
       class="btn btn-danger"
       data-href="url"
       data-toggle="modal"
       data-target="#confirm-delete"
>

@lang('request.list.delete')
</button>

@include('elements.confirm-delete-modal')
```

My jquery:

```
$('#confirm-delete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('.btn-ok').attr('href', $(e.relatedTarget).data('href'));
});
```

Comment: Do you have any error in the console that you can share with us?

Comment: Is your modal inside other `div`. What happens if you move it to just before the end `</body>` tag?

Comment: @nakov I have no errors in my console

Comment: why not you do $('#confirm-delete').modal('show');

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin Yes that's it! Didn't know this. Thank you!

Comment: @EmtiazZahid I need to do some other stuff when showing the modal, not just only showing it.

Comment: i think you can do other stuff before modal show.